# Delete useless answers button?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I just started deleting my useless answers (answers with no up-votes) and I was thinking that a cool feature would be to have a button that just auto-magically deletes these useless answers.

Comment: -1 Just because an answer does not have upvotes, does not mean that it's useless. Same goes for answers with downvotes.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't post useless answers? ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess a button that magically deleted useless answers would be good, but answers with no up-votes aren't necessarily useless; you shouldn't just mass delete all of them

Comment: if they are not new and nobody has given them any up-votes they are on topic that no1 cares about or wrong or useless.

Comment: @01 Or the people that found them don't know to upvote them, or don't have enough rep to upvote them, or they haven't helped anyone yet but they might in the future

Comment: It sounds a bit like a contradiction, you want to have a button, but you don't want to use it. Or was the emphasis on **magically** ?

Comment: @01: I've found answers to my questions here - answers that were useful, 0-votes, and **two years old**. I upvoted them, but if the original poster had been impatient and deleted when they didn't get any upvotes for a few months, my problem wouldn't be solved. `<yoda>` Patience learn you must, hm? `</yoda>`

Comment: @bernd Exactly; my point was that if SO could invent a button that only deletes completely useless answers, that would be good, since the answers are useless after all, but his criteria for useless answers isn't very good

Comment: @Michael I use two criteria to delete my 0 voted answers: 1st when there is are other nearly identical answers or 2nd when other answers a much superior. Answering sql questions that occurs quite frequent. Further I check not to delete valuable comments (e.g.  containing links ). In short I have little hope that there might be some tool which reduces my work very much.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is a good idea, to do this automatic. It will blindly erase valuable comments perhaps containing useful links. Please take a look at what you are deleting.